# Move files to different server using SSH?

Tags: ssh

I have a large number of files which I would like to move from one server to another server.

What would be the best way of doing this without overloading my original server?

Should I tar each folder and then download to my computer and then upload to the other server?

What would be the SSH command of doing that?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 4):

From the SCP Reference Manual:

> Any file name may contain a host and user specification to indicate
>   that the file is to be copied to/from that host. Copies between two
>   remote hosts are permitted.
>
> -p Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.
>
> -r Recursively copy entire directories.

```
scp -rp username@source:/foldername/ username@destination:/foldername
```

Using tar to create one file may reduce the load slightly because there won't be as much file handling overhead on one file...ymmv. Compression with gzip will reduce bandwidth but will put a greater load on the source server to compress the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your worries are unfounded regarding 'overloading the server'. Any way you move the files off is going to slightly load the server but it is a trivial amount.

`tar`ing and `gzip`ing the the files first will reduce the amount of network traffic, but the action of `tar`ing and `gzip`ing will require work by the first server.

Simply `tar`ing is probably of not much value - it's one big file versus lots of smaller ones (the same size in total).

There's little actual value in downloading then uploading - unless you want a copy as well - your network connection to each server is likely worse than the one between the two servers.

This is more a question for SuperUser though.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that i don't have root access to the servers, nor that i am that of a specialist anyway - i know how to use SSH commands... My host provider still hasn't come back to me..

Answer (score 0):

1. tar+gzip/bzip2 and scp to copy
2. rsync (it could work over ssh)